# All return values are undefined from Facebook log in button

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

After successfully log in, i try to get a few fields from the user.
All of them are `undefined` other than the `name` and `ID`. The pop up indeed ask those permission which I granted.

Read all posts here and non offered a solution that work other than using `tokens`(?) which I am not sure how, and never see in FB examples.

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
      console.log("connected");
      console.log("Access Token: " + response.authResponse.accessToken);

      testAPI();
    } else {
      console.log("not connected");
    }
  },
  { scope: "email,user_age_range,user_friends" }
);

function testAPI() {
  console.log("Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ");
  FB.api("/me", function(response) {
    console.log("name: " + response.name);
    console.log("email: " + response.email);
    console.log("id: " + response.id);
    console.log("friends: " + response.user_friends);
    console.log("age: " + response.user_age_range);
    console.log("end");
  });
}
```

If I print `response` i get an error :
**Uncaught ReferenceError: respond is not defined**

Comment: How does `response` looks like?

Comment: And this is a question how?

Comment: maybe because it's `response` and not `respond` ... ?

Comment: You need to _ask_ for the fields you want, otherwise you will only get a few default fields returned.

Comment: @04FS ask means what? can you provide more details so I can do something to fix it ?

Comment: @samb102 sorry , so if it helps the printed respond is :  respond: [object Object]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who wonder, first, the way to read it is  :

```
  FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
          console.log('name: ' + response.name);
          console.log('email: ' + response.email);
     });
```

*Second*, a few points to notice:

1. Remove your app on your facebook profiles (under Apps) otherwise every time you test, FB will automatically grant access even if you wish to add *more* permissions.
2. Remove cache from your browser every new test because FB will keep the previous state and changes will not take effect.(sometimes, even updated deployments will not)
3. You should deploy your website, with me -  local host is not working with FB because they require https.

Testing Facebook is a little bit hassle.